# C# Com Object - Out of Memory

Tags: c++, .net, multithreading, winapi, crystal-reports-xi

I created a small C# library that exposes a COM object which is used to display a CrystalReport viewer.

I have such a code in my C# test app that works as needed and report is shown

```
public partial class ReportHolder : UserControl
    {
        private string _reportFilename;
        private string _datasourcePath;

        public ReportHolder(string reportFilename, string datasourcePath)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _reportFilename = reportFilename;
            _datasourcePath = datasourcePath;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_reportFilename))
                return;

            ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
            doc.Load(_reportFilename);

            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            string serverName = string.Format("Driver={{Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)}};DBQ={0};DefaultDir={0};DriverId=533;FIL=dBase 5.0;UserCommitSync=Yes", _datasourcePath);
            connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
            connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.DBFile;

            Tables tables = doc.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
            }

            //doc.VerifyDatabase();
            crViewer.UseWaitCursor = true;
            crViewer.ReportSource = doc;
            crViewer.RefreshReport();
            crViewer.UseWaitCursor = false;
        }
    }
```

Now I have the same UserControl inside my C# Com Object

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("F8FB6B66-5A15-4396-8A81-D7B8655E2869")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Se32ComBridge : ISe32ComBridge
{
    public Se32ComBridge()
    {  

  }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

public IntPtr ShowReport(IntPtr hWndParent, string reportFileName, string datasourcePath)
{
    ReportHolder reportHolder = new ReportHolder(reportFileName, datasourcePath);
    SetParent(reportHolder.Handle, hWndParent);
    reportHolder.LoadReport(reportFileName, datasourcePath);
    return reportHolder.Handle;
}
}
```

where `hwndChild` is an actual HWND from a window in WinAPI C++ application.

which I instantiate from a native C++ application, like this

```
sam32_net_bridge::ISe32ComBridgePtr pIBridge(__uuidof(sam32_net_bridge::Se32ComBridge));
_bstr_t reportFilename(_reportFilename.c_ptr());
_bstr_t datasourcePath(_datasourcePath.c_ptr());
pIBridge->ShowReport((long)hWnd, reportFilename, datasourcePath, &_controlHandle);
```

And here I'm getting such an exception

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Start()    at
>   System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler
>   onFrameChangedHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.Animate(Boolean animate)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.Animate()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()    at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.ShowProgressAnimation(Boolean
>   enabled)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_ReportSource(Object
>   value)    at sam32.net.bridge.ReportHolder.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in
>   \app\sam32.net.bridge\ReportHolder.cs:line
>   52    at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

it looks to me like the Threading does something funny when not running in a full .NET environment. So, I'm wondering, what else shall I set properly in this COM object that it will function as needed.

Thx

Comment: One funny thing the Thread class does is allocate one megabyte of address space, required for the thread's stack.  If that fails because there isn't enough left then you get OOM.  There is no strong hint that this has anything at all to do with COM or Crystal Reports.  OOM happens.  A memory profiler is recommended here.

Comment: On the same PC, I'm running the same userControl using same report, but inside a pure .NET and all works as needed. I smell something different here. :)

Comment: Well, sure, the memory that your C++ code requires is not included.  The less memory you use, the lower the odds for OOM.  Old fashioned problem btw, time to start targeting x64.

Comment: is not about this, the PC has a lot of memory available. Most likely Threads behave somewhat wrong when not hosted in a pure .NET environment.

Comment: All modern PCs have a lot of memory available.  You can only actually use it when you target x64.  "behave somewhat wrong" is definitely not going to get you anywhere, use a profiler to gather hard facts so you can stop guessing.